# Sort on checkbox value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I want to sort a column of true/false checkboxes in a table with AngularJs (i.e. show all empty checkboxes first and vice versa).

The checkboxes are bound to a model and the checkmarks show up accordingly, but I am not able to sort the column. Is it possible to do this in angular?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not something intended.. The intend is I have 5 checkboxes, and two of them are selected, then I need to sort them, having checked box first or viceversa

Answer (score -1):

Check this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

And this is the demo provided by Angular for this functionality

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example103-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="orderByExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.friends =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
      $scope.predicate = '-age';
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  [ <a href="" ng-click="predicate=''">unsorted</a> ]
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=false">Name</a>
          (<a href="" ng-click="predicate = '-name'; reverse=false">^</a>)</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'phone'; reverse=!reverse">Phone Number</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'age'; reverse=!reverse">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```